# Ignore delete failed files when using "git clean"

Tags: cmd.exe, git-bash

When I use `git clean -dfx` while the solution is opened in Visual Studio, I got
`Unlink of file '.vs/MyService/v15/Server/sqlite3/db.lock' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)`

How do I ignore that in the command? Actually, what I want is `git clean -dfx & build && assemble` so I donot have to input  `n` every time.

Comment: Does `echo n|git clean -dfx` work?

Comment: It worked but with `warning: failed to remove .vs/MyService/v15/Server/sqlite3/db.lock: Invalid argument`. But is shows invalid argument when I enter 'n' myself.

Comment: Appending a space plus `2>nul` or `>nul` should suppress error messages. Anyway, I'd first try to find out why the error or warning appears after all...